# Issue with <MarkerClusterer></MarkerClusterer> from @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

im having a problem with MarkerClusterer component from @react-google-maps/api.I try to render markers on the map but none of them show up. I have a scenario where multiple markers have exact the same position, so i need to use MarkerClusterer. Is there anyone out there who uses the same package, and have a working MarkerClusterer? Please help.

Code:

```
const { GoogleMap, LoadScript, MarkerClusterer, Marker } = require('../../')
const ScriptLoaded = require('../../docs/ScriptLoaded').default

const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: '400px',
  width: '800px',
}

const center = { lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887 }

const locations = [
  { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
  { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
  { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
  { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
  { lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968 },
  { lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657 },
  { lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905 },
  { lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196 },
  { lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222 },
  { lat: -37.75, lng: 145.116667 },
  { lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708 },
  { lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858 },
  { lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299 },
  { lat: -37.7737, lng: 145.145187 },
  { lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978 },
  { lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119 },
  { lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692 },
  { lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218 },
  { lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694 },
  { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506 },
  { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315 },
  { lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438 },
  { lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352 },
]

const options = {
  imagePath:
    'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m', // so you must have m1.png, m2.png, m3.png, m4.png, m5.png and m6.png in that folder
}

function createKey(location) {
  return location.lat + location.lng
}

const MapWithMarkerClusterer = () => {
  return (
    <ScriptLoaded>
      <GoogleMap id='marker-example' mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} zoom={3} center={center}>
        <MarkerClusterer options={options}>
          {(clusterer) =>
            locations.map((location) => (
              <Marker key={createKey(location)} position={location} clusterer={clusterer} />
            ))
          }
        </MarkerClusterer>
      </GoogleMap>
    </ScriptLoaded>
  )
}
```